# How to groupby and sum on different column pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which I want to group by the column `Letter` and `From`. Example df below:

```
   Letter  Price From        RT      To   
0   A      4     2020-06-04  11  2020-06-05
1   B      12    2020-06-04  11  2020-06-05
2   A      20    2020-06-04  11  2020-06-05
3   A      5     2020-06-04  11  2020-06-05
4   B      89    2020-06-05  11  2020-06-06
5   A      56    2020-06-05  11  2020-06-06
6   B      1     2020-06-06  11  2020-06-07
```

In standard SQL I would write a query following to achieve the desired results.

```
SELECT 
 Letter,
 From,
 SUM(Price),
 MAX(RT)
FROM
  some.table
GROUP BY Letter,From
```

I tried with the following but it didn't work.

`df.groupby(['Letter','From']).sum(['RT','To'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['From'] = pd.to_datetime(df['From'])
df['To'] = pd.to_datetime(df['To'])
df = df.groupby(by=['Letter', 'From'], as_index=False).agg({
    'Price': 'sum',
    'RT': 'max'
})
print(df)

  Letter       From  Price  RT
0      A 2020-06-04     29  11
1      A 2020-06-05     56  11
2      B 2020-06-04     12  11
3      B 2020-06-05     89  11
4      B 2020-06-06      1  11
```

Answer (score 0):

The columns to be aggregated need to be right after the `groupby` to work as a slicer just as you would slice a standard df. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) for the parameters you can pass to `sum`. But you actually need [aggregate or agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to be able to aggregate each column with a different function.

```
df.groupby(['Letter','From'])[['Price', 'RT']].agg({'Price': sum, 'RT': max})
```